# Error: The value of the property 'warn_redirect' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a page in one of my ASP.NET applications (VB) that relies on a 3rd party service being live, and I'm using jQuery to display an overlay if this service is found to be down.  I've been using the same approach for other warnings in the app - the difference with this one is that it needs to redirect after the user clicks the button on the warning popup to remove the overlay.  For some reason I'm getting the error "Error: The value of the property 'warn_redirect' is null or undefined, not a Function object."

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!  My code follows:

jQuery

```
function warn_redirect(msg, title, nextpage) {
    // show modal div
    //alert(obj.id);
    $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $("body").append("<div id='popup_overlay'></div><div id='popup_window'></div>");
    $("#popup_overlay").addClass("popup_overlayBG");
    $("#popup_overlay").fadeIn("slow");

    // build warning box
    $("#popup_window").append("<h1>" + title + "</h1>");
    $("#popup_window").append("<p id='popup_message'><center>" + msg + "</center></p>");
    $("#popup_window").append("<div class='buttons'><center><button id='continue' class='positive' type='submit'>OK</button></center></div>");

    // attach action to button
    $("#continue").click(popup_remove_redirect(nextpage));

    // display warning window
    popup_position(400, 300);
    $("#popup_window").css({ display: "block" }); //for safari using css instead of show
    $("#continue").focus();
    $("#continue").blur();
}

function popup_remove_redirect(nextpage) {
$("#popup_window").fadeOut("fast", function () { $('#popup_window,#popup_overlay').trigger("unload").unbind().remove(); });
$("body", "html").css({ height: "auto", width: "auto" });
$("html").css("overflow", "");
window.location.href = nextpage;
```

}

Here is the VB.NET calling code:

```
If Status = "DOWN" Then
            Dim clsUtility As New Utility
            clsUtility.Emailer("email@company.com", "email@company.com", "", "", "The Service Is Down!", "Please investigate")
            Dim ScriptString As String = "<script language='javascript'>"
            ScriptString += "warn_redirect('Some warning message.', 'Warning', 'AnotherPage.aspx');"
            ScriptString += "</script>"
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "warnscript", ScriptString)
            'Response.Redirect("AnotherPage.aspx?ID=" & Session("SelKey") & "&UN=" & Header1.UserNumber) //this didn't work either
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the definition of your script is loaded after the StartupScript is invoked.

You have to include your .js file before the StartupScripts in your page. Look at the "source code" in your browser, and you'll see a bunch of script tags like this:

```
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=eoXLgy ... 847d" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

These tags are the scripts inserted as StartUp scripts. Make sure your script is inserted before this in your .aspx (or .master). Perhaps you'll have to include them in the head tag.

By the way, creating a global function, like you warn_redirect, it's not a good practice. You should, at least, namespace it like this:

```
window.MyFunctions = {
   warn_redirect = function (msg, title, nextpage) { /* your code */ }
}
```

And call it like this: `MyFunctions.warn_redirect`.

In this way, you have it better organized, and avoid possible collisions with other functions with the same name.

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback.  I did move the references to the jQuery library file and my jQuery source file into the head, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Then you should open the browser javascript console in the browser developer tools (F12 in Chrome or IE or Firefox+Firebug) and refresh the page to see if there is any error. (I prefer Chrome or Firefox+Firebug to IE). Sometimes, an error in another .js file avoids the code of the following files to work.

Comment: Also, in the console, let me know what result you get when you type warn_redirect. Undefined? Anything else?. You can also try debugging the js file where you define the function (for example, in Chrome console, look for the file in Sources (the right arrow button on the top left of the window), and set a breakpoint (click on the margin) to get suer it gets executed without error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
If Status = "DOWN" Then
            Dim clsUtility As New Utility
            clsUtility.Emailer("email@company.com", "email@company.com", "", "", "The Service Is Down!", "Please investigate")
            Dim ScriptString As String = "<script language='javascript'>"
            ScriptString += "window.onload = function(){warn_redirect('Some warning message.', 'Warning', 'AnotherPage.aspx');};"
            ScriptString += "</script>"
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "warnscript", ScriptString)
            'Response.Redirect("AnotherPage.aspx?ID=" & Session("SelKey") & "&UN=" & Header1.UserNumber) //this didn't work either
        End If
```

As JQuery is already included, you can also use the below statement instead.

```
ScriptString += "$(function(){warn_redirect('Some warning message.', 'Warning', 'AnotherPage.aspx');});"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  I did try both ways, but am still getting the same error as before.

Comment: You can also precede the above code with another `RegisterStartupScript` that loads the JavaScript file. `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "warnscriptfile", "<script src='myfile.js' />")
`